# += and incremental growth give two different values in C

Tags: c

I have a chunk of code that is measuring the length of a block of text.  I need the length of a gap of an unknown number of `N` inserted within the text (which consists of `G`, `A`, `C`, and `T` only) as well as the total length of the text block containing the gap(s).  I am working one character at a time via a `fgetc()` and I devised two different ways to calculate the values, but they are giving me vastly differing results.

Method A:

```
...
} else if (in != '\n') {
    scafLength++;
    if (in == 'N') {
//Read entire gap
        while ((in != 'G') && (in != 'A') && (in != 'C') && (in != 'T') && (in != '>')) {
            if (in != '\n'){
                gapLength++;
                scafLength++;
            }
            in = fgetc (inFile);
//If it's at the end of the file
            if (feof (inFile)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        ...
        Do stuff
        ...
//Reset for next gap and allow normal processing of next character after the gap
        gapLength = 0;
        fseek (inFile, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}
```

Method B:

```
...
} else if (in != '\n') {
    scafLength++;
    if (in == 'N') {
//Read entire gap
        while ((in != 'G') && (in != 'A') && (in != 'C') && (in != 'T') && (in != '>')) {
            if (in != '\n'){
                gapLength++;
            }
            in = fgetc (inFile);
//If it's at the end of the file
            if (feof (inFile)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        scafLength += gapLength - 1;
        ...
        Do stuff
        ...
//Reset for next gap and allow normal processing of next character after the gap
        gapLength = 0;
        fseek (inFile, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}
```

`>` is a character used to denote a new scaf.  This is the only area where scafLength and gapLength are altered, except to set them back to 0 for a new gap/scaf.  Now, I expected an off-by-one in method A, which is why I made method B, but the numbers I'm getting are way off.  Method A is giving me 16,777,216 as the longest scaf while Method B gives me 23,080,784.  The real longest scaf (verified by multiple other programs) is 23,428,386 and there are not 5 million gaps to account for a fencepost error (the most is 180).

I'm curious why would these two approaches give such drastic differences?  Also, if anyone can see a mistake I'm making, I'd appreciate it being pointed out.

EDIT: From the first few comments I need to clarify, the gapLength is reset to 0 after it serves it's purpose in the same `else if ()`.  I've updated the code.

Comment: `scafLength += gapLength - 1;` ： I seem `gapLength` should be reset.

Comment: for both methods,  right after the line: if (in == 'N') {, the var gapLenght needs to be re-set to 0.

Comment: I already do reset it, I just didn't post it, sorry for the confusion.  I've updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with my variable type caused by my compiler. `gapLength` and `scafLength` were originally declared as `int`.  Having run out of options, I switch them to `long` and the code performs perfectly.  Apparently my compiler has the short `int` limit of 32,768.

Answer (score 1):

In the first version it looks like you only incrementing scafLength when `(in != '\n')` but in the second version you continually add the value of `gapLength - 1` whenever you enter the outer if-block and not just when you enter the inner `(in != '\n')`

Presumably the value of gapLength isn't reset and therefore the second version grows faster.

As your code is incomplete it's really hard to say, so consider this a guess.

Comment: I already have it reset within the same `else if ()` block, I have updated my code to show as much, sorry for the confusion.